# Launch IE explorer without showing window?

Tags: internet-explorer, shell, command-line

I dont know if this is possible but when at command prompt, I do something like:

C:\explorer.exe "http://LaunchURL"

it tries to open up a internet explorer browser window and goes to the LaunchURL. However, I do not want the browser window to show up as the LaunchURL is a click once deployment URL...So basically, what happens is it shows up briefly and then the clickonce deployment starts up as expected.

Is there a way to fake the system so as not to show the window or hide it perhaps?

Thanks

Comment: `explorer.exe` is the Windows Explorer (what you use to browse the filesystem). Which app are you actually launching?

Comment: I am launching a click once deployment URL link..."http://webserlocation/Sales.application" file...

Comment: @Matt explorer does though accept http URIs as parameters. Since it then passes it to whatever your default browser is, it's the same as just entering the URI in a run prompt.

Comment: @JonHanna what I was wondering was if the OP mistyped `iexplorer.exe`, perhaps launching it via WinEx would bypass the window opening. It seems to be a moot point, however.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure.  You can do this through PowerShell and an IE object.  Just don't make it visible:

```
$ie = new-object -com "InternetExplorer.Application"
$ie.navigate("http://launchurl")
```

If you ever needed to see the window for troubleshooting, use this:

```
$ie.visible = $true
```

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for your reply...I am trying to invoke this command from a regular command line...is this possible without using a powershell? Or am i missing something here? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You could call a powershell script file or script block from the command line, but PowerShell will have to be involved in some way.  If you have powershell installed wherever you want to run this it won't be an issue.  If some clients don't have powershell installed (which shouldn't be the case in a semi-current (xp+) environment) you will have an issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to launch ClickOnce installation. You'd better use appref-ms link file, OS will execute it and start normal ClickOnce installation right away.

Make an App.appred-ms file, with the following content:

```
    http://server/appFolder/App.application#App.application, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0000000000000000, processorArchitecture=msil
```

Also if you're launching IE as invisible consider parameter "Silent" (Sets or gets a value that indicates whether the object can display dialog boxes.)

Comment: Thats what I ended up doing...Also, in my exact case, I am laucnhing the appref-ms file on system launch...It works fine on windows 7 and xp but it fails on Vista!! Im trying to figure out what to do in this case.

Comment: What exactly fails? (Appref link or executable) for executable there's  one thing you can try.

Comment: I am trying to launch the appref-ms file on startup on Windows vista...that fails

Comment: It seems vista blocks files of type appref-ms on startup

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the ability to run code on the target machine (you've an existing app there), then use WebClient or HttpWebRequest to download the installer to a temporary folder, and then have the shell execute it.

Otherwise, this is pretty much what click-once is meant to do. You can improve the presentation by giving people the URI of a page which presents some pretty greeting, how-to, thank you and "your download should begin shortly, if not then please click..." before a script moves to the click-once URI, hence causing it to be downloaded and run.