# How to open URL in background in Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

I am trying to open an URL in background which works fine:

```
$ie = new-object -com "InternetExplorer.Application"
$ie.navigate("www.bing.com")
```

But when I set my server url to either of these, the IE window appears.

```
$ie.visible = $false
$ie.navigate("192.168.167.132\test.html")
$ie.navigate("http://192.168.167.132\test.html")
```

Comment: Why do you need to open it in the backround? What does it do for you? If you tried the visible property I would add that into your question so you don't get flagged as a dupe since we see no attempt of that in your question.

Comment: Nobody is going to be able to re-create this behaviour as we don't have access to your local website.

Comment: Matt > you're right. I'll add that

Answer (score 4):

See the post here:
[Mentions a .Visible parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11849502/launch-ie-explorer-without-showing-window)

Here, Chris wrote:

> Sure. You can do this through PowerShell and an IE object. Just don't
>   make it visible:

```
> $ie = new-object -com "InternetExplorer.Application"
> $ie.navigate("http://launchurl") If you ever needed to see the window
```

> for troubleshooting, use this:

```
> $ie.visible = $true
```

Do this

```
$ie = new-object -com "InternetExplorer.Application"
$ie.visible = $false
$ie.navigate("http://192.168.167.132/test.html")
```

Comment: sure, I said it works with google.com but it doesn't work with my url : 192.168.167.132\test.html

Comment: did you try and put a http:// in front of the IP address? And perhaps include $ie.visible = $false?